# How to debug Portable executable for AMD64 in IDA PRO?

Tags: ida, debugging, amd64, intel

How can I debug Portable executable for AMD64 in IDA PRO if I have Intel processor?

Comment: I'd think if the executable runs on your system/processor, it would be debuggable in IDA Pro. Otherwise - IDA doesn't do cross-debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give any details about your machine's processor. Does it support 64-bit architecture? Does it implement the x86-64 instruction set?

This is only a problem if your machine's Intel processor does not support 64-bit architecture and/or does not does not implement the same instruction set as AMD64 processors.

However, AMD64 processors and most 64-bit Intel processors (other than Itanium-family processors, for example) implement the same instruction set: [x86-64](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf).

In other words, PE binaries compiled to target the x86-64 instruction set architecture will execute on Windows boxes regardless of whether they utilize an AMD64 processor or a 64-bit Intel processor.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109569/do-intel-and-amd-processor-have-the-same-assembler
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64

Comment: I have MacBook Pro 2016

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to debug using IDA.